# Consider: $\tan x^3=-\frac{3}{2x^3}$ problem with the logic of finding two values for $\tan$?

Tags: trigonometry

$\tan x^3=-\dfrac{3}{2x^3}$

$\tan x^3=\dfrac{2}{3x^3}$

$3\tan x=\dfrac{2}{x^3}$

$3\tan x^3=2$

$\tan x^3=\dfrac{2}{3}$

Hang on!! Now $\tan x^3 =\dfrac{2}{3x^3}$ but also: $\tan x^3=\dfrac{2}{3}$

How is this possible? Or is there a problem in my workings?

Comment: I believe that it would be a informative exercise to you to attempt to include justification for each step of your algebraic manipulations. Especially the transition between your third and fourth expressions.

Comment: I multiplied the whole expression through by $x^3$

Comment: It seems that (ignoring what I assume is a typo going from $tan(x^{3})$ to $tan(x)$) you only multiplied the right side of the expression by $x^{3}$, the left being unaffected by the operation.

Comment: Well $x^3*$$x$$=$$x^3$ (*=multiply)

Comment: This is not the case (unless $x=1$). Generally it holds that $x^{3}\cdot x=x^{4}$.

Comment: But $x^3$ $*x^1 = x^3$

Comment: When you multiply two expressions involving exponents where the base is the same, the rule is to sum the exponents: $x^{a}\cdot x^{b}=x^{a+b}$.

Comment: Ah of course, sorry I seem to have got my indices laws confused, in that case may you correct my calculations please, thanks.

Comment: Also note, on potentially a more serious note w.r.t. algebra, that the following does not hold: $tan(a)=\frac{b}{c}\not\leftrightarrow tan(a\cdot c)=b$ rather $tan(a)=\frac{b}{c}\leftrightarrow c\cdot tan(a)=b$.

Answer (score 2):

There are a few errors in your reasoning.

1. $-\dfrac{a}{b}$ is not the same as $\dfrac{b}{a}$.
2. From $3\tan x^3=\dfrac{2}{x^3}$ you can't deduce $3\tan x^3=2$. What makes you think it's possible?

Set $y=x^3$ for simplicity: with $\tan y$ we denote a single number obtained by computing the tangent of $y$.

From
$$
3\tan y=\dfrac{2}{y}
$$
you can deduce that
$$
3\cdot y\cdot(\tan y)=2
$$
which is quite different from $3\tan y=2$.

Comment: Ok thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

You can always graph both solutions and see if they match up. If they don't match, then you can dig a little deeper to see if and why there are actually more than one solutions.